# Dialogs plugin does not work since I installed Vibration Plugin

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

I'm using cordova 3.4.0 to develope an android's application.

I installed the "Dialogs plugin" (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs) and it worked, but later of install the vibration plugin it didn't work anymore.

I checked all permissions but nothing. Here i show you how i've configurated my files

I using it:

```
177             document.addEventListener("backbutton",  function (ev) {
178                 ev.preventDefault();
179                 ev.stopPropagation();
180                 navigator.notification.confirm('Exit?', function (res) {
181                     if (res === 1) {
183                         navigator.app.exitApp();
184                     } else if ( res === 2 ) {
186                         self.lock();
187                     }
188                 }, 'Close application',['Exit','Lock', 'Cancel']);
189             });
```

This works before install Vibration plugin, there does not throw errors.

My plugins/android.json: http://paste.kde.org/porysxppg

My config.xml (cutted):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.myapp.test" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    ...
    <feature name="Notification">
            <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Notification" />
    </feature>
</widget>
```

Complete list of plugins installed:

```
com.cesidiodibenedetto.filechooser 1.0.0 "FileChooser"
com.monday.contact-chooser 0.2 "Contact Chooser"
de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification 0.7.4 "LocalNotification"
org.apache.cordova.contacts 0.2.10 "Contacts"
org.apache.cordova.device 0.2.10-dev "Device"
org.apache.cordova.dialogs 0.2.8-dev "Notification"
org.apache.cordova.file 1.1.0 "File"
org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser 0.4.1-dev "InAppBrowser"
org.apache.cordova.splashscreen 0.3.0 "Splashscreen"
org.apache.cordova.vibration 0.3.9-dev "Vibration"
```

Answer (score 0):

When.. I resolve it fixing feature tag on config.xml:

```
<feature name="Vibration">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.vibration.Vibration" />
</feature>
<feature name="Notification">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.dialogs.Notification" />
</feature>
```